# Python - Two Number Sum (time and space complexity)

Tags: python

I'm solving the classic problem of finding two numbers from an array that sum to a given value.

Can anybody please check whether my analysis of time and space complexity is correct on this one?

```
# O(n) time | O(1) space 
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    for x in array:
        y = targetSum - x
        if y!=x and y in array:
            return [x, y]
    
    return []
```

Comment: It is nearly impossible to solve this problem with O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: Executing `y in array` already takes linear (O(n)) time. This is inside the `for x in array` loop, so this O(n) has to be multiplied by n (the number of elements you loop over). Hence quadratic (O(n²)) time, not linear. Also note `y != x` has nothing to do with the problem and should be removed for the code to give correct results, leaving only `if y in array:`

Comment: I think the `y!=x` should actually be checking indices.  As things are, `twoNumberSum([2,2],4)` will be false.  If you remove it as Stef suggests, `twoNumberSum([1,2],4)` will be true.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori If the list is sorted, we can solve it with two pointers approach in linear time.

Answer (score 5):

This code fails given `[0, 1, 1]` and `2` as inputs: it should return `[1,1]` but fails because the two numbers are identical.  So it fails review, without any further analysis.

Scaling is poorer than you believe, if `array` is a list, since `in` is generally linear in the list length.  Since `in` is used inside the `for` loop, time taken is proportional to O(n²).

When no result is present, I would probably choose to return `None` rather than an empty list.